# how to have internet access in ubuntu in virtualbox via bridged network?

Tags: networking, wireless

how my laptop is using a wireless network adaptor for internet connection. How may I configure my Ubuntu in virtualbox to have internet access via the wireless network adaptor?

Comment: You need to first configure the network settings in virtualbox: You may wish to review http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: The first answer on the linked duplicate should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Choose bridged network adapter and choose your wifi card. Refresh mac address on that view (it's under advanced options) and it should work. If your host has Internet, virtual box machine should have it also